# After finding files, find subsequently received file

Tags: vba, file-search

This code finds files that have a certain date in the file name, then saves them in a specified folder.

When another file that has the same date comes in, I want to add this file to the collection of previously found files. It doesn't find the new file.

If I delete the previously made folders and run it from scratch it will find all the files. It is like the recursivefilesearch isn't refreshing the folder and just using the previously found files.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Merge_Data()

    Application.StatusBar = "Finding today's files"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = "folder\"
    
    ' Ask user what date they would like to merge the files for
    Dim dateString As String, TheDate As Date
    Dim valid As Boolean: valid = True
    Dim Input_Box_Msg As String

    Input_Box_Msg = "What Date would you like to merge the files for? " & vbNewLine & "Please enter date in format mm/dd/yyyy: "
    
    Do
        dateString = InputBox(Input_Box_Msg)
        
        If IsDate(dateString) Then
            TheDate = DateValue(dateString)
            valid = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid date. Please enter date in format mm/dd/yyyy:"
            valid = False
        End If
    Loop Until valid = True
    
    'Edit_1: Based on Comment
    ' Obtain current date in format yyyymmdd
    Dim Current_Date, Current_Date_1 As String
    
    Current_Date = Format(TheDate, "yyyymmdd")
    Current_Date_1 = Format(TheDate, "yyyy_mm_dd")
    
    ' Find all files in folder that contain previously input date by the user
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    ' Regex object with previously input date by the user
    objRegExp.Pattern = Current_Date
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Set colFiles = New Collection
    Dim f As Variant
    
    ' Recursively search through folders for files that match today's date
    RecursiveFileSearch FilePath, objRegExp, colFiles, objFSO
    
    Dim Combined_Path As String
    Combined_Path = "new_folder\"
    Combined_Path = Combined_Path & Current_Date & "\"
    
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    
    ' .xlsx extension number
    FileFormatNum = 51

    Path = Combined_Path
    Folder = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)
 
    ' Create New folder to store today's files
    If Folder = vbNullString Then
        VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (Path)
    End If
    
    Dim Full_File_Path As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim File_Type_1 As String
    Application.StatusBar = "Saving today's files in new folder"
    
    ' Save Files that match criteria in new folder in .xlsx format
    For Each f In colFiles
        Workbooks.Open f
        FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        MsgBox FileName
        File_Type_1 = FSO.GetExtensionName(FileName)
        If File_Type_1 = "xls" Then
            FileName = FileName & "x"
            Full_File_Path = Path & FileName
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Full_File_Path, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, CreateBackup:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            File_Type_1 = ""
            FileName = ""
            Full_File_Path = ""
        ElseIf File_Type_1 = "xlsx" Then
            If Left(FileName, 11) = "Merged_File" Then Exit For
        Else
            Full_File_Path = Path & FileName
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Kill Full_File_Path
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Full_File_Path, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, CreateBackup:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            FileName = ""
            Full_File_Path = ""
            File_Type_1 = ""
        End If
    Next
    
    FilePath = ""
    Current_Date = ""
    Current_Date_1 = ""
    Set f = Nothing
    Set colFiles = New Collection
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
    RecursiveFileSearch FilePath, objRegExp, colFiles, objFSO

End Sub

Sub RecursiveFileSearch(ByVal targetFolder As String, ByRef objRegExp As Object, _
  ByRef matchedFiles As Collection, ByRef objFSO As Object)

    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objSubfolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolders As Object

    'Get the folder object associated with the target directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(targetFolder)

    'Loop through the files current folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then
            matchedFiles.Add (objFile)
        End If
    Next

    'Loop through the each of the sub folders recursively
    Set objSubFolders = objFolder.Subfolders
    For Each objSubfolder In objSubFolders
        RecursiveFileSearch objSubfolder, objRegExp, matchedFiles, objFSO
    Next

    'Garbage Collection
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objSubFolders = Nothing
    Set objSubfolder = Nothing

End Sub

Function FileExists(ByVal FileToTest As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = (Dir(FileToTest) <> "")
End Function

Function StripNumber(stdText As String)
    Dim str As String, i As Integer
    'strips the number from a longer text string
    stdText = Trim(stdText)
    For i = 1 To Len(stdText)
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(stdText, i, 1)) Then
            str = str & Mid(stdText, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    StripNumber = str ' * 1
End Function
```

Comment: can u list the files in the directory, the ones it finds and the ones it doesnt and the input date as entered? thanks

Comment: Input date is 02/13/2021. It finds the files with names like xxx_xxx_xxxx_20210213_933551152.xls, xxx_xxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxx_20210213_933610397.xls. It works fine when I run it the first time, but say another file comes in, if I re-run the macro it won't find the new file  even though it's in the same location. Thanks for your help

Comment: one observation - i dont think you are guaranteeing the date is in mm/dd/yyyy format even though you request that in the message box prompt - the line `TheDate = DateValue(dateString) ` will use the Windows Date Settings as a locale, so that might cause some confusion if your locale is not in fact US. e.g. if your locale us UK and "01/08/2020" is entered this will be cause `TheDate` to be August 1st. Just one observation that may or may not be an issue as I starting reading the code from the top

Comment: comments overlapped - given that date you supplied, my point above would not be an issue

Comment: one other point - combined date can be constructed by using `current_date = Format(TheDate, "yyyymmdd" )` and `current_date_1 = Format(TheDate, "yyyy_mm_dd" )` without having to do the string manipulation and rebuilding

Comment: `If Left(FileName, 11) = "Merged_File" Then Exit For` if this file comes up first then no other files get processed

Comment: Yeah I think what Tim mentioned about the order of my loop was my problem . Thank you both for your assistance!

Comment: You don't want to `Exit For` in that scenario - just go to the next iteration

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Comment: One observation `Dim Current_Date, Current_Date_1 As String` is only declaring the second variable as a string, the first will be a variant. If you want both to be strings it shuold be `Dim Current_Date As String, Current_Date_1 As String`